# How to find index funds that contain specific stock?

Tags: stocks, investing, index-fund, research

Is there a process that would let you look for index funds that contain specific stock.

Like, find index funds that contain `Alphabet NASDAQ: GOOGL`.

I know how to do it manually - you just go to each individual index fund and look under portfolio, but the process is slow and tedious, so I am hoping that there is a 'better way'

Comment: You might have better luck if you rephrase to ask about a better process. Asking for off-site tools or resources is explicitly off-topic here.

Comment: @glibdud Hi, thanks for the tip I have edited the question

Comment: Google "ETF Fund Overlap".  There are sites that perform this.

Comment: @BobBaerker Bingo https://www.etfrc.com/funds/stocklocator.php Thank you so much you just saved me days of misery. Could you post it as the answer I would like to accept it.

Comment: Yep, you found it.  That's the one.  You found what you need so there's no need to post it as answer just for some posterity points :-).

Comment: @BobBaerker , are you being sarcastic? I don't get your comment.

Comment: @Aganju - No sarcasm at all.  I offered a possible solution.  Matas Vaitkevicius did a web search and found the web site that I use (site/product recommendations aren't much liked here).  He then graciously thanked me for my answer and suggested that I post it as an answer because he would like to suggest it.  He's happy since it 'saved him days of misery'.  I don't feel the need  to post a formal answer just so that I can get some rep points.   I'm happy.  He's happy.  How about you?

Comment: The concept of stackexchange is not necessarily to answer a single person's question, but make the answer available to future seekers. Not putting it in an answer disables that, and you are around long enough to know this. If this question is not worthy of keeping (because it's simple to google it), we should close it, and if it is worthy, it should have an answer. If you don't care about the points, fine, but the site cares about its concepts. - anyway, bynow, someone has added it as answer already.

Comment: @Aganju - There's rigidity in the system here and a lot of the time, I have no clue why some answers are accepted or rejected or why  some comments are preferred as answers.  I'm more concerned with Pay It Forward and I don't have the time or inclination to meticulously learn the precise rules of the game so I leave that to the purists.

Comment: The rules are straightforward: answer as an answer, comments are for comments. Not complicated. And ignore ratings and up/down votes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Many of the online tools will allow you to look at the financial details of the company. They typically have a section/tab that list the largest investors. This includes people, investment companies and mutual funds.

for example:

https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/GOOG/holders?p=GOOG

> Top Mutual Fund Holders
>
> ```
> Holder                                    Shares      Date Reported   % Out   Value  
> Vanguard Total Stock Market Index Fund    8,222,028   Jun 29, 2019    2.41%   8,887,272,285
> Vanguard 500 Index Fund                   6,032,827   Jun 29, 2019    1.77%   6,520,943,032
> Growth Fund Of America Inc                3,494,307   Sep 29, 2019    1.02%   4,259,560,233
> SPDR S&P 500 ETF Trust                    3,359,630   Nov 29, 2019    0.99%   4,384,182,764
> ```

Answer (score 3):

Copied from the comment by @BobBaerker, so some poor sap wouldn't have to experience my last few days...

There is an [online system that allows doing just that](https://www.etfrc.com/funds/stocklocator.php)

One can look for overlaps in funds and also find funds with specific stock

[image]